# An interesting teaching by a native speaker

Tags: pronunciation

Watching [**this video,**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msZ0T0RBqrM), in which a native speaker is teaching Japanese learners about English,

The teacher is saying about "Wait a minute", from 3:16～

Wait a minute = Waitamini(small t)

To me personally, I can perfectly hear the last "t" of the sentence.
(For example, when your would like to "press on"(emphasize) **Wait,**)

To native speakers, is this a "true statement"?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this too basic to be destined to be deleted?

Comment: Don't see why. I think it's interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The teacher seems to suggest the t is very quiet, rather than missing entirely (in the captions at least, by writing the 't' far smaller than the other letters).

< WAITAMINIt

That reasonably suggests the spoken form, especially in American English, where terminal 't' sounds become an almost silent tongue flap. It's not so much that the t is omitted, but that it's weakened so far as to be almost inaudible. Saying it right now in my at one time Estuary (London) English accent, I can sense that I don't really form the 't' properly either, but mine is more of a glottal stop than an American tongue flapped 't'.

Both the glottal stop and the American 't' sound are not the same as not voicing the letter at all, but they're ways of sounding the t in a weaker way which is much less obviously voiced than a hard British English 't'.

For what it's worth, I'd imagine the American English 'wait a minute' as sounding more like:

> waidaminid

Comment: "I'd imagine the American English 'wait a minute' as sounding more like: waidaminid" - Gedouddahere!